# Angular 2 - Multiselect install by typings.json

Tags: typescript, angular, multi-select

I am trying to install the angular2-multiselect: https://github.com/igariok1990/angular2-multiselect

I did it with all the 3rd party plugins like this in typings.json:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "bootstrap.v3.datetimepicker": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/bootstrap.v3.datetimepicker/bootstrap.v3.datetimepicker.d.ts#a83eb4912e674b3492ce77567337642a7e6c584f",
    "moment": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/moment/moment.d.ts#1be6a281906e5cd179a97c86bd58ebf9cdc9c6a5",
    "moment-node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/moment/moment-node.d.ts#b090bcf9ba9f756ec8ff53e7707269729172a325",
    "jquery": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jquery/jquery.d.ts#661fc869669af796c6048483e999dce5732eed72",
    "bootstrap.multiselect": "github:ravendb/ravendb/Raven.Studio.Html5/Scripts/typings/bootstrap.multiselect/bootstrap.multiselect.d.ts#f05d3b934bcbc22ab5e87fad4a81e4309bde6534",
    "angular2-multiselect": "github:igariok1990/angular2-multiselect/src/app/components/multiselect.ts#d075c9ff8c2f904cc3f122d41276619d8b2886f9"
  }
}
```

But when I write npm install it throws me errors: Unable to resolve (slug to multiselect.d.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem that the module `angular2-multiselect` is available in NPM.

See the result of the request `https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=angular2-multiselect`:

> Sorry, no results for ‘angular2-multiselect’

Comment: is there an alternetive to install this plugin?

Comment: The alternative I see is to checkout the source code and link it to your project...